# I am having weird issues with "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.5.0" but not 1.0.0. Is there any way to tell what might be causing these?

Tags: sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit app with `package.json` showing `"@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0"` and it uses netlify functions to interface with mongodb and everything works fine.

I then installed, in another folder, `npm create svelte@latest app` and it shows `"@sveltejs/kit": "^1.5.0"`. Everything else the same. Copied over `src/static/netlify` folders, installed Netlify adapter, set up `netlify.toml` file, `.env` file. Installed same version dependencies.

Under 1.5, I get several weird problems like it wont update a record or it has an issue with a `{#each` loop or duplicate keys. Not just one issue. Several. I change `package.json` entry to `"@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0"` and `npm i` and all the problems disappear so its definitely 1.5. I updated Node. No difference. I updated axios and mongodb and same issue.

Is there any way to find out what changes took place from 1.0 to 1.5 to try to figure this out? I would like to use the latest SvelteKit version but can't with these errors.

Comment: did you try the update to 1.6?

Comment: no, i will check that thanks

Comment: I just did a new install of sveltekit (npm create svelte@latest my-app) and it shows as 1.5.0. Is there a 1.6 version?

Comment: weird you still see 1.5. since today it should be available 1.7 too, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sveltejs/kit?activeTab=versions

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Turned out to be an issue with mongodb 5.1 so for now reverting to mongodb 4.13.0 all is well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be mongodb 5.1.0. Even now with Sveltekit 1.8.3 there is an issue with mongodb 5.1.0, so I reverted to mongodb 4.13.0 and that works fine.